# Preloading ExtJs classes in ExtJs 5 application

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I generated ExtJs5 application skeleton using `sencha` utility. I don't use generated  `app.js` during development, instead I am working from application home directory using autogenerated `index.html`.

It works pretty slow because browser loads ~500 JavaScript files and stylesheets before it starts loading my own classes & styles.

Is there a way to preload *all* ExtJs resources in several files? In prev. versions of ExtJs there was `ext-all.js` file. But in the recent ExtJs version this file does not actually contain all classes but rather references to them for later loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is still full `ext-all[-debug].js` but not in Ext unzipped root but in `build` subdirectory.